# How do I know the last iteration of for loop?

Tags: php, for-loop

I have a `for` loop in my code:

```
$d = count( $v2['field_titles'] );

for( $i=0; $i < $d; $i++ ) {
  $current = 3 + $i;
  echo 'current is' . $current;
}
```

How do I know the last iteration if I don't know exact number of `$d`?

I want to do something like:

```
$d = count( $v2['field_titles'] );

for( $i=0; $i < $d; $i++ ) {
  $current = 3 + $i;

  if( this is the last iteration ) {
   echo 'current is ' . $current; 
   // add sth special to the output
  }
  else {
    echo 'current is ' . $current;
  }
}
```

Comment: $i should be $d - 1, at the last iteration...

Comment: In this simple case, you just do the `add sth special to the output` after the loop completes.

Comment: @Vohuman Not a duplicate at all.  Did you read the content or only the title?

Comment: @JasonMArcher The idea is the same. A super simple comparison.

Comment: There is no duplicate like mentioned (1070244), since the other question is about FOREACH loop and the actual question is about a FOR loop. My Approach would be:
`if($i+$increase > $sum) {
  $data->last = true;
}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if($i==$d-1){
   //last iteration :)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer `while`, to `for` personally. I would do this:

```
$array = array('234','1232','234'); //sample array
$i = count($array); 
while($i--){ 
    if($i==0) echo "this is the last iteration"; 
    echo $array[$i]."<br>"; 
}
```

I've read that this type of loop is a little faster but havn't personally verified. It's certainly easier to read/write, imo.

in your case, this would translate to:

```
$d = count( $v2['field_titles'] );

while($d--) {
  $current = 3 + $d;

  if($d==0) {
   echo 'current is ' . $current; 
   // add sth special to the output
  }
  else {
    echo 'current is ' . $current;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort but I will use `for` anyways.